# Correct way of inserting new row into SQL table, but only if pair does not exist

Tags: mysql

This has been discussed before, however I cannot understand the answers I have found.

Essentially I have a table with three columns memo, user and keyid (the last one is primary and AUTO_INC). I insert a pair of values (memo and user). But if I try to insert that same pair again it should not happen.

From what I found out, the methods to do this all depend on a unique key (which I've got, in keyid) but what I don't understand is that you still need to do a second query just to get the keyid of the existing couple (or get nothing, in which case you go ahead with the insertion).

Is there any way to do all of this in a single query? Or am I understanding what I've read (using REPLACE or IGNORE) wrong?

Comment: The pair in your case is defined by `memo, user`. However, you have a primary key (which is also unique), and it's `auto_increment` - that means you will never get the same primary key. But, you can get the same combination of `memo, user`. To prevent that, you add another key - `UNIQUE(memo, user)`. Now you can't have the same memo and user and you can perform queries such as `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and such. However, such a pair might not be exactly optimal and without knowing further details (data types of memo and user), this is as far as I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a UNIQUE KEY on user + memo,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_user_memo UNIQUE (memo,user)
```

and then using `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE` according to your needs when inserting.  Your current unique key is the primary key, that is all well and good, but you need a 2nd one in order to not allow the insertion of duplicate data.  If you do not create a new unique key on the two columns together, then you'll need to do a `SELECT` query before every insert to check if the pair already exists.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Clear as day, now!